# Upload multiple images with image-picker plugin and send to controller with ajax in asp.net core?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I Use the 'spartan-multi-image-picker' plugin for uploading...

I want to send the images selected by this plugin to the controller ...

But only one file is sent, I do not know where the problem is?

I saw almost all the same posts on this site but it did not help!!

Html Inputs created by this plugin :

```
<input id="ImageName" class="form-control spartan_image_input" accept="image/*" data-spartanindexinput="0" style="display : none" name="fileUpload[]" type="file">
```

Jquery Code :

```
Form_Data.append("ImagesGallery", $('#ImageName')[0].files[0]);

 $.ajax({
    url: '/AdminPanel/Product/AddAndUpdateProduct',
    data: Form_Data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
    //
    }
});
```

View Model :

```
public class AddProductViewModel
{     
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> ImagesGallery { get; set; }

}
```

Controller :

```
public IActionResult AddAndUpdateProduct(AddProductViewModel model)
    {
      //
    }
```

Plugin Code:

```
 var template = `<div class="${groupClassName} spartan_item_wrapper" data-spartanindexrow="${count}" style="margin-bottom : 20px;float:right; ">`+
                            `<div style="position: relative;">`+
                                `<div class="spartan_item_loader" data-spartanindexloader="${count}" style=" position: absolute; width: 100%; height: ${rowHeight}; background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7); z-index: 22; text-align: center; align-items: center; margin: auto; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; display : none; font-size : 1.7em; color: #CECECE">` +
                                    `${uploadLoaderIcon}` +
                                `</div>`+
                                `<label class="file_upload" style="width: 100%; height: ${rowHeight}; border: 2px dashed #ddd; border-radius: 3px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom : 5px; position : relative; display: flex; align-items: center; margin: auto; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column;">`+
                                    `<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-spartanindexremove="${count}" style="position: absolute !important; right : 3px; top: 3px; display : none; background : #ED3C20; border-radius: 3px; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height : 30px; text-align: center; text-decoration : none; color : #FFF;" class="spartan_remove_row"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>`+
                                    `<img style="width: ${placeholderImageWidth}; margin: 0 auto; vertical-align: middle;" data-spartanindexi="${count}" src="${placeholderImageTarget}" class="spartan_image_placeholder" /> `+
                                    `<p data-spartanlbldropfile="${count}" style="color : #5FAAE1; display: none; width : auto; ">${dropFileLabel}</p>`+
                                    `<img style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; display:none;" class="img_" data-spartanindeximage="${count}">`+
                                    `<input id = "ImageName" class="form-control gallery__product spartan_image_input" accept="image/*" data-spartanindexinput="${count}" style="display : none"  name="${fieldName}" type="file">`+
                               `</label> `+
                            `</div>`+
                       `</div>`;
```

Can you help me thanks?

Comment: `contentType: false` - It's been a while, since I've used jQuery, but I've never seen that one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo to pass multiple files to action with ajax:

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="coba1"></div>
</div>
    <button onclick="uploadfiles()">upload</button>
    <script>
    $("#coba1").spartanMultiImagePicker({
            fieldName: 'fileUpload[]'
        });
        function uploadfiles() {
            var Form_Data = new FormData();
            document.getElementsByName("fileUpload[]").forEach((el) => {
                if ($(el)[0].files[0] != undefined)
                Form_Data.append('ImagesGallery', $(el)[0].files[0]);
            }
                
            );
            $.ajax({
                url: 'AddAndUpdateProduct',
                data: Form_Data,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    //
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

action:

```
public IActionResult AddAndUpdateProduct(AddProductViewModel model)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks,I tried this code before, it didn't work.Because this plugin does not make one input but four inputs

Comment: Can you share your view code rather than generated html code?

Comment: Makes a lot of code that can not be copied,But consider the four inputs similar to the one I asked in the question.Each input selects a file

Comment: You only need to show the code with `spartan-multi-image-picker` plugin.

Comment: I edited my questions, you can see

Comment: I updated my answer with `spartan-multi-image-picker` plugin.